# Creating an Array of Structures on the Heap in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, heap-memory

I need to declare an array of structures on the heap, then transfer data from parallel arrays on the stack and from calculations into each structure. I declared

```
struct Grades
{
    string  studentName;
    int     scores[4];
    double  average;
};

....

Grades *art1301 = new Grades;

....

(art1301 + i)->studentName = names[i];

for((int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
(art1301 + i)->scores[j] = exams[i][j];

(art1301 + i)->average = average;
```

My program accesses the first record, but it crashes after it accesses the first field of the second record. I don't understand why it works for the first record, but dies in the middle of the second? Am I accessing the structure correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a hint: This is wrong (for your purposes): `Grades *art1301 = new Grades;`

Comment: You are declaring only one Grades struct on the heap. You do not have enough memory allocated for more than one, so you probably get a writing violation consequentially. To be able to work one more than one Grades on the heap, then this change should be made `Grades* art1301 = new Grades[i+1]`, where I assume i + 1 is the number of structs you want allocated.

Comment: Please don't use pointer arithmetic to index an array. Use the indexing operator `[]`.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I thought that was the wrong way to declare the structure, but every way I tried to edit it, the compiler rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate an array, you need the array form of `new`, with the square brackets:

```
Grades *art1301 = new Grades[200];
//                          ^^^^^
```

The array size can be a dynamically determined quantity.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the array size put the entire program working. My assignment is now complete.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allocating memory for an array, you are allocating only for one element.

As someone said in the comments, the key is in the `new Grades` instruction

In addition, unless you have another `i` variable declared before (which is a bad practice), that code doesn't compile because `(art1301 + i)->studentName = names[i];` will not find variable `i`